# declare mutable string with varying size dynamically

Tags: string, assembly, macros, dynamic-memory-allocation, gnu-assembler

I made my own string declarator with macro in GNU Assembler in x64 machine.

```
.macro declareString identifier, value
  .pushsection .data
    \identifier: .ascii "\value"
    "lengthof.\identifier"= . - \identifier
  .popsection
.endm
```

This is how to use it:

```
.data
ANOTHER_VARIABEL: .ascii "why"

.text
_start:
  declareString myString, "good"
  lea rax, myString
  mov rbx, lengthof.myString
```

So basically my macro is just `label` maker.

So in debugger, `rax` will be value of myString address because `myString` basically just a `label`.
And `rbx` will be value of myString length (4).

So If I want change myString from `good` which has 4 chars to `rocker` which has 6 chars at runtime, I'm afraid it will `overwrite another variabel` due to size collision.

I heard about heap memory but I'm not sure how does it work. I only know about stack, but I'm used to use stack as temporary backup.

So how do I declare mutable string in assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as in C; if you want to use static storage (in `.data`) for the characters themselves (like `static char myString[4] = "good";` note not including a terminating 0 byte), you actually need to reserve enough space for the largest you ever want this string to be.  Like `static char myString[128] = "good"`.

In your case, like `.space 124` after your `.ascii` would be a total of 128 bytes reserved after the label `myString`.

You're correct that you shouldn't write past the size you reserve, although it would come *after* `ANOTHER_VARIABEL`, not before, since that part of your `.data` section is earlier in your source than where you use the macro containing `.pushsection`

If you wanted to do dynamic allocation, you might want to make an `mmap(..., MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, ...)` system call to allocate 1 or more pages of memory, then copy bytes into it.  (You're writing a `_start` so I'm assuming you're not linking libc.)

You could make your global variable a *pointer*, but if you free the old pointer and allocate a new one (or mremap to the new size), you should start with runtime allocation and init of it.  You don't want to `munmap` a page of `.rodata`.

Or instead of `mmap`/`munmap`, Linux `mremap(MREMAP_MAYMOVE)` can ensure that the allocation is big enough to hold your whole string without copying it.  MAYMOVE lets it pick a new virtual address if there aren't enough free virtual pages following the currently pointed-to page, but without copying the actual data in the already-allocated pages.

There are tons of Q&As about making system calls in assembly so I'm not going into details about that; you can think about how you're managing memory in terms of system calls to make, separately from implementing it in asm.  Thinking about it in C is pretty much equally valid; asm doesn't add much in terms of being able to declare static data or make system calls.  Other than the fact that you *could* in asm make sure that a page of `.data` was exclusively dedicated to this string, with no other things using it, so you *could* potentially let `mremap` unmap that page from your .data and map it at a different virtual address.

Comment: it seems ```mmap``` is using secondary storage (SSD/HDD) to store ```myString``` instead of physical memory (RAM). Correct me if I'm wrong. If not wrong, then it will slower the process due to Read and Write access time in secondary storage.

Comment: @CitraDewi: no, first of all a file-backed memory mapping doesn't actually sync to disk on every read/write; only eventual write-back so it still uses DRAM (and CPU cache).  But more importantly  I'm talking about `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` which is like a *private* (not shared) mapping of `/dev/zero`.  There is no backing file/device, just like stack space. It's only backed by swap space if anything when dirty.  That's what most malloc implementations use behind the scenes for large allocations.  (glibc malloc uses `sbrk` for small allocations, carving that up for smaller allocations.)

Comment: So I just bit understand more about heap after read some, so CMIIW. Basically heap is similiar like stack except heap is start at end of ```.text``` and going to higher address when grow. If I allocate manually dynamically at runtime without kernel syscall, will there any possibility crash accident between another process due to accessing another process memory region?

Comment: @CitraDewi: "The heap" isn't a real thing; these days it includes any source of dynamic allocation, e.g. the pool that malloc allocates from, including `mmap`.  What you're describing is the classic layout where dynamic allocation is done at the end of `.data`/`.bss`, sort of like growing the `.bss`.  In Unix, "the break" is the end of that area; that's what the `brk` and `sbrk` system calls do.  (Check the Linux man page carefully: the kernel API is different from the POSIX API; glibc keeps a static variable internally.  Or see examples on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: But yes, you need to do something to ask the kernel for space, because reading/writing an unmapped page will segfault.  Space past the end of the `.data` section is usually the `.bss`, and beyond that there's memory your asm source doesn't mention with `.space` directives, but is accessible because memory protection has page granularity.